# Update variable on new month without fail

Tags: java, android

I have a variable that needs to be updated the first time my app is started after a new month has begun. It needs to be reliable. Any idea on the simplest way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roger, I would just use a [`SharedPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the month that the app was last launched and check it in the `onCreate()` method of your main `Activity`.

just perform the following in your `onCreate()`

1. Get value of `SharedPreference`
   (check if its never been initialized
   = first launch ever)
2. Get current month value
3. If they aren't equal, the month has changed
4. store new month value in `SharedPreference`
5. do whatever you wanted based on a new month starting